# Schedule task when user idle

Tags: windows-8.1, task-scheduler

I'm trying to schedule a task on Windows 8.1 Pro, such that after a certain time of day (for example midnight), and only when the computer hasn't been used for a period of time (15 minutes), it puts the computer into a sleep state.

Windows task scheduler has an option that at first glance appears to do exactly this, however [Microsoft's definition of idle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383561%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), also includes tasks running on the PC. I do have tasks running on the PC, but it's a LAN game server that's running in the background that is quite happy to be suspended in this manner.

I'm not using power saving options, because I actually want the game server to be running during specific hours (when nobody is sat in front of the PC) and have a separate task that wakes the PC at a given time. I could just schedule a task to sleep the computer at a specific time, but I'd rather not do it this way, just in case I end up using the PC later than normal one night.

I'm a Windows developer and have considered writing a simple screensaver that just puts the computer to sleep when the screensaver is triggered (during specific hours), as this would probably solve the problem very well, but I was wondering if there is an easier automated way of doing this?

Could I create a scheduled job that changes the power saving policy at certain times of the day?

Comment: You can use [Powercfg.exe](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc748940(v=ws.10).aspx) to change the power saving policy from a (scheduled) script. `Powercfg -change -standby-timeout-ac 15` will change the standby for the `current power scheme` to 15 minutes. Is that what you've been asking for?

Comment: @boboes that sounds likely. I'll give it a try (you might want to post that as an answer instead of a comment so I can accept if it works).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Powercfg.exe](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc748940(v=ws.10).aspx) to change the power saving policy using a (scheduled) script.

This will change the standby timeout for the `current power scheme` to 15 minutes:

```
Powercfg -change -standby-timeout-ac 15
```

Comment: I've created two scheduled jobs, the first is exactly as above which is trigged at midnight to allow the PC to sleep when the user is no longer using the PC, and another which sets the -standby-timeout-ac value to zero to prevent it from sleeping (and the task also wakes the PC from sleep) at the time I want the game server to start up again. I'm sure this will do exactly what I need. I'll test overnight tonight. Thanks for your help.